# Rewrite python script runner browser and make inline (./emcc ...)command for build single emscripten test cases

Tags: emscripten

I want to know how to make inline args for emcc from python script runner.

I don't get it who `SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME` var go passing from cmd line.

It is ok when we jave usually `main (arg c)` but in this case it is a simple `main()`

I wanna do it just like python runner browser command do.
 What ever i pass "FILENAME" or FILENAME compiler follow in errors.

**This is program for porting :**

> File: *sdl_image.c*

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012 The Emscripten Authors.  All rights reserved.
 * Emscripten is available under two separate licenses, the MIT license and the
 * University of Illinois/NCSA Open Source License.  Both these licenses can be
 * found in the LICENSE file.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int testImage(SDL_Surface* screen, const char* fileName) {
  SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load(fileName);
  if (!image)
  {
     printf("IMG_Load: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
     return 0;
  }
  assert(image->format->BitsPerPixel == 32);
  assert(image->format->BytesPerPixel == 4);
  assert(image->pitch == 4*image->w);
  int result = image->w;

  SDL_BlitSurface (image, NULL, screen, NULL);

  int w, h;
  char *data = emscripten_get_preloaded_image_data(fileName, &w, &h);

  assert(data);
  assert(w == image->w);
  assert(h == image->h);

  SDL_FreeSurface (image);
  free(data);

  return result;
}

int main() {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(600, 450, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);

  int result = 0;

  // result |= testImage(screen, SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME "/" SCREENSHOT_BASENAME); // absolute path
  // assert(result != 0);

  // chdir(SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME);
  result = testImage(screen, "./" SCREENSHOT_BASENAME); // relative path

  assert(result != 0);

  SDL_Flip(screen);

  printf("you should see an image.\n");

  SDL_Quit();

#ifdef REPORT_RESULT
  REPORT_RESULT(result);
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

For example this is interest case :

```
  def test_sdl_image(self):
    # load an image file, get pixel data. Also O2 coverage for --preload-file, and memory-init
    shutil.copyfile(path_from_root('tests', 'screenshot.jpg'), 'screenshot.jpg')
    create_test_file('sdl_image.c', self.with_report_result(open(path_from_root('tests', 'sdl_image.c')).read()))

    for mem in [0, 1]:
      for dest, dirname, basename in [('screenshot.jpg', '/', 'screenshot.jpg'),
                                      ('screenshot.jpg@/assets/screenshot.jpg', '/assets', 'screenshot.jpg')]:
        self.compile_btest([
          'sdl_image.c', '-o', 'page.html', '-O2', '-lSDL', '-lGL', '--memory-init-file', str(mem),
          '--preload-file', dest, '-DSCREENSHOT_DIRNAME="' + dirname + '"', '-DSCREENSHOT_BASENAME="' + basename + '"', '--use-preload-plugins'
        ])
        self.run_browser('page.html', '', '/report_result?600')
```

***My attempt's :***

```
  emcc tests/sdl_image.c -s -lSDL -USE_SDL=2 -USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -o TEST.html
```

```
  emcc tests/sdl_image.c -s -lSDL -USE_SDL=2 -USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 --preload-file screenshot.jpg  -DSCREENSHOT_DIRNAME="screenshot.jpg" -DSCREENSHOT_BASENAME="screenshot.jpg" -o TEST.html -O2 --use-preload-plugins
```

***Error log :***

```
>  n file included from <built-in>:325: <command line>:6:14: warning:
> extra tokens at end of #undef directive [-Wextra-tokens]
> #undef SE_SDL=2
>              ^
> // <command line>:7:20: warning: extra tokens at end of #undef directive [-Wextra-tokens]
> #undef SE_SDL_IMAGE=2
>                    ^
> // tests/sdl_image.c:49:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'screenshot'   result |= testImage(screen,
> SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME "/" SCREENSHOT_BASENAME); // absolute path
>  ^ <command line>:8:28: note: expanded from here
> #define SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME screenshot.jpg
>  ^ tests/sdl_image.c:52:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'screenshot'   chdir(SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME);
>  ^ <command line>:8:28: note: expanded from here
> #define SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME screenshot.jpg
>  ^ tests/sdl_image.c:53:35: error: expected ')' result = testImage(screen, "./" SCREENSHOT_BASENAME); //
> relative path
>  ^ <command line>:9:29: note: expanded from here
> #define SCREENSHOT_BASENAME screenshot.jpg
>  ^ tests/sdl_image.c:53:21: note: to match this '(' result = testImage(screen, "./" SCREENSHOT_BASENAME); //
> relative path
> ^ 2 warnings and 3 errors generated.
```

***Last attempt*** :

```
sh-3.2# emcc -s SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME="screenshot.png" tests/sdl_image.c -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -o TEST.html --preload-file tests
shared:ERROR: Assigning a non-existent settings attribute "SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME"
shared:ERROR:  - perhaps a typo in emcc's  -s X=Y  notation?
shared:ERROR:  - (see src/settings.js for valid values)
```

**UPDATE:**

After i remove flags and put hardcoded values for screenshot.png

Cmd line :

> emcc tests/sdl_image.c -o TEST.html -s WASM=O2 -s -lSDL -s -lGL
>   -USE_LIBPNG=1 --memory-init-file 1  --preload-file tests --use-preload-plugins

I get new type of error (in browser) - Compiler success :

```
> failure to dynamicAlloc - memory growth etc. is not supported there,
> call malloc/sbrk directly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a wrong format of parameters. Your command:

> emcc tests/sdl_image.c -s -lSDL -USE_SDL=2 -USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -o TEST.html

The correct way to pass arguments is:

> emcc tests/sdl_image.c -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -o TEST.html

Basically `-s EMSCRIPTEN_SETTING=value` format is used for Emscripten settings specified in [settings.js](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/settings.js).

Also you **should not** pass `-lSDL`, `-lGL`, or something. Dynamic library linking works completely different from conventional C/C++ toolchains.

Comment: Looks better but i still need to pass args SCREENSHOT_DIRNAME and SCREENSHOT_BASENAME. I try too pass but my browser log say "no file /tests/screeshot.png ...

Comment: `-D` flag should work. Just be careful when passing `"` as string literal. It is just your directory `/tests` doesn't exist in the browser. Note that saving file is done in a Javascript sandbox, meaning you **won't get the file as a local file** in your system.